# Determine security zone of iexplore.exe process

Tags: internet-explorer, security-zone

Internet Explorer launches Intranet and Trusted sites each in a separate iexplore.exe process running at Medium Integrity level.

Is there a way to determine the specific security zone of an iexplore.exe process?

I am working on a Task Manager tool and would like to distinguish iexplore.exe processes between the various security zones Restricted, Internet, Intranet and Trusted.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the [IInternetSecurityManager::MapUrlToZone](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537133(v=vs.85).aspx) method.  Yes, it's C++ and, yes, it's, er...[complicated](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ef5627e4-2b87-4cba-a964-bbaf741f3911/how-to-get-ie-zone-value-when-a-site-is-loaded-in-ie-browser-using-c?forum=csharpgeneral).

*Update, based on the comment:*

Security zones are URL-based; process isolation is more to do with protected mode, integrity levels, and AppContainer permissions.  Not all details are available through public APIs for security reasons.

IIRC, the short answer you're looking for involve searching access tokens for [specific SIDs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379554(v=vs.85).aspx) (security descriptors) ([context here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn519896(v=vs.85).aspx)).  But, that's going to need further context to fully understand.  You'll want to read the full [collection of articles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn519894(v=vs.85).aspx) and then backfill some of the details using EricLaw's highly [detailed](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2012/03/23/understanding-ie10-enhanced-protected-mode-network-security-addons-cookies-metro-desktop.aspx) [backgrounders](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/03/10/internet-explorer-beware-cookie-sharing-in-cross-zone-scenarios.aspx).  (That's two separate links, BTW).

If searching for the SID doesn't lead you to the answer you're looking for, the larger collection of related "how-to" tasks [may help](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379609(v=vs.85).aspx).

Hope this helps...

-- Lance

Comment: Sorry, I should have stated more clearly that I need to determine the security zone of a process. So the input is a process ID or handle. MapUrlToZone needs an URL.

Comment: I expanded the answer to provide more context and, I hope, point you in the right direction.